# DataGridView design X & Y scroll with fixed header, visible grid line, even column width

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I'm making an admin panel and I have DataGridView on each page.

At the moment, it is not showing x &y gridLines and column width is arbitrary. I've used ItemStyle width 10%, but still doesn't really do the trick.

Here is my source code

```
<td class="auto-style9" colspan="2">
    <div style= "Overflow:scroll; overflow-x: scroll; max-height: 220px; width: auto">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUpPer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCatID" HeaderText="Sub category ID">
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
```

Here is my design

[image: My messy grideView]

x scroll is not appearing and my gridView is not showing the entire columns. I only can change heard text color not the text color of data. I'm using table and div.

I have 15 of GV looking like this..... Can anyone help me to design a good looking gridView?? Thanks~

C#, VS 2012

Comment: I use two Gridviews. One for the header, one for the rows. Both using the same css. I set the widths of the columns on the pre_Render event of one of the gridviews and get perfectly aligned, scrollable grids. You have to spend a bit of time determining the size of the user's screen (which I do on the first call to the first page and store the width and height of the screen) and use this to set the height and width of both gridviews. The div containing the gridview with the data is set 20px wider to allow for the scrollbar.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry for the late comment but how to create 2 gridview? I'm very new to programming and I don't know about javascript so little detail would be great! Thanks!